# Initialize swagger without web.xml to disable it in production

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger with Jersey 2 and spring bootstrap. Currently I'm looking a solution to disable swagger on production as it will be concern in case any user 
uses the API's with the swagger UI.

I'm registering io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig servlet in web.xml and passing init parameters to it like api.version and swagger.api.basepath. Along with this I'm registering package to scan as io.swagger.jaxrs.listing so that org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig will take care to prepare swagger UI.

I got to know from internet that we can achive this byb using @profile annotations. But I experienced that If we register any class in Web.xml, even though you are using @Profile on that class level, it will not work as the class going to be loaded at context load.

I have static contents in my project like swagger-ui-min.js, swagger-ui.js, index.html etc to load the swagger.

With this setup, how can I disable swagger UI in production? Also if some one have experience on , should swagger could be disabled in production or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a flag which allows to load the Swagger Servlet only when you are not in production (here for Swagger 2):

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import io.swagger.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource;

@ApplicationPath("") // no application path after the context root
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(...); // your main service
        if (notInProduction) { // a flag telling that you are not in production
            classes.add(OpenApiResource.class);
        }
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is got sorted with the help of environment variable. I just registered swagger UI package only in case of environment variable set to development. For other environment this package will not be registered. 

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: So you should submit your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
String enable_swagger_ui = System.getenv("ENABLE_SWAGGER_UI");
 if( enable_swagger_ui != null && enable_swagger_ui.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            packages("io.swagger.jaxrs.listing");
```

You just need to add the ENABLE_SWAGGER_UI in system environment variable where you want to enable swagger.